# how can i set the reminders time with Intent.ACTION_EDIT?

Tags: android, calendar

I've tried to look for options, how can I "control" the Intent.ACTION_EDIT? My code is:

```
public void addEvent(long beginTime, boolean allDayOrNot, long endTime, String title) {          
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", beginTime);
    intent.putExtra("allDay", allDayOrNot);
    intent.putExtra("endTime", beginTime+60*60*1000);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("description", title);
    intent.putExtra("hasAlarm", true);
    startActivity(intent);  
}
```

As you can see I sent many extras for "control" the ACTION_EDIT screen,
I searched for an extra the set the reminders time (for the alarm).
My goal is that the ACTION_EDIT screen will appear already with my specific reminders time like "30 min before". I didn't find an answer. Is there such extra? If not - is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use timer task for this , http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

Comment: i saw the TimerTask, as i understand it's kind similar to Timer.. (not sure i understand it right). anyway, i didn't understand how it will help me to my problem, my final goal is to create new event in the calender.. with a specific reminders time..